# vba excel copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get some help with following 2 question:

First,

I have Sheet1 which loops and gets different values from website for cells

B68, B69, B67, A61, D85 and B73, I would like to write VBA to copy these values in Sheet2 in order

A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1

but with my current code if Sheet1 any cell is empty it will shift copied cell  (up(End(xlUP), I need to create with every set of data next row, regardless of value, even some copied cells are empty...

Second,

Add condition that every time D85 in Sheet1 is empty then it will copy value from cell D86, regardles the value of D86 ...

```
 DoEvents

    'Copy to Another sheet

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("B68")
        .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("B69")
        .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("B67")
        .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("A61")
        .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("D85")
        .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("B73")


    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks for the last row of `UsedRange` in `Sheet2`, even if some cells are empty. Then it copies the data from `ws` sheet to `Sheet2`.

```
Dim des_ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set des_ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = des_ws.UsedRange.Rows(des_ws.UsedRange.Rows.count).row + 1

With des_ws
    .Range("A" & LastRow) = ws.Range("B68")
    .Range("B" & LastRow) = ws.Range("B69")
    .Range("C" & LastRow) = ws.Range("B67")
    .Range("D" & LastRow) = ws.Range("A61")
    If ws.Range("D85") = "" Then
        .Range("E" & LastRow) = ws.Range("D86")
    Else
        .Range("E" & LastRow) = ws.Range("D85")
    End If
    .Range("F" & LastRow) = ws.Range("B73")
End With
```

Comment: The OP is adding record to Sheet2 as the data on sheet1 is retrieved from a website. You are only overwriting the values on Sheet2 and not adding records to it.

Comment: @ThomasInzina i just saw I missed that request.

Comment: @ThomasInzina LOL, I agree, the problem is when I asked a few questions here (not so easy) I didn't get the answer as fast as we are giving them

Comment: @ThomasInzina thanks, maybe you can help me with my question here ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @ThomasInzina chech the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420375/excel-vba-error-467-when-trying-to-open-a-powerpoint-presentation